# Displaying password validation errors in django

Tags: django, validation, templates

I'm trying to validate my registration form. I'm using djanga-registration, it already has password validation function.

In my registration form, I'm using this function :

```
{% if form.errors %}
   {% for field in form %}
      <div class="error_message">
           {{ field.errors }}
      </div>
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

It displays all errors except the password matching validation which is:

```
def clean(self):
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    Verifiy that the values entered into the two password fields                                                                                                                                                                                         
    match. Note that an error here will end up in                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    ``non_field_errors()`` because it doesn't apply to a single                                                                                                                                                                                          
    field.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

    """
    if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
        if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'no no no'))

    return self.cleaned_data
```

In my other view , change password, it displays password matching validation, but not the one i wrote ("no no no"), i think it displays the default one.

So any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like you implemented the view correctly but your template doesn't have:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#form-objects

```
"""
Verifiy that the values entered into the two password fields
match. Note that an error here will end up in
``non_field_errors()`` because it doesn't apply to a single
field.

"""
```